# python on Linux: os.pipe() with cumulative byte counter?

Tags: python, linux, pipe

Is it possible to get a cumulative count of bytes written to an `os.pipe()`? I tried `os.fdopen(...).tell()` but got `IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek`. Is there some other way to wrap the `fd` to get a cumulative byte count?

Comment: The Linux kernel doesn't have such a counter built in for pipes (and sockets etc.). Python file objects don't have such a counter built in. You can add your own counter, see the answer by personal_cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently most libraries are perfectly happy with setting `sys.stdout` to any class that has `write()` and `flush()` methods. A custom `write()` method can count the characters written.